# Constant Scan spooling

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I have a table with a few dozens of rows. Simplified setup is following

```
CREATE TABLE #data ([Id] int, [Status] int);

INSERT INTO #data
VALUES (100, 1), (101, 2), (102, 3), (103, 2);
```

And I have a query that joins this table to a set of table value constructed rows (made of variables and constants), like

```
DECLARE @id1 int = 101, @id2 int = 105;

SELECT
    COALESCE(p.[Code], 'X') AS [Code],
    COALESCE(d.[Status], 0) AS [Status]
FROM (VALUES
        (@id1, 'A'),
        (@id2, 'B')
    ) p([Id], [Code])
    FULL JOIN #data d ON d.[Id] = p.[Id];
```

Query execution plan is showing that optimizer's decision is to use `FULL LOOP JOIN` strategy, which seems appropriate, since both inputs have very few rows. One thing I noticed (and cannot agree), though, is that TVC rows are being spooled (see area of the execution plan in the red box).

[image: Constant Scan spooling]

Why optimizer introduces spool here, what is the reason to do it? There is nothing complex beyond the spool. Looks like it is not necessary. How to get rid of it in this case, what are the possible ways?

---

The above plan was obtained on

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU11) (KB4077063) - 12.0.5579.0 (X64)

Comment: Related [suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38346115-optimizer-to-consider-constant-scan-spooling-elimination) at feedback.azure.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why optimizer introduces spool here, what is the reason to do it? There is nothing complex beyond the spool.

The thing beyond the spool is not a simple table reference, which could simply be duplicated when the left join / anti semi join [alternative](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/26/nested-loops-join/) is generated.

It may *look* a little like a table (Constant Scan) but to the optimizer* it is a `UNION ALL` of the separate rows in the `VALUES` clause.

The additional complexity is enough for the optimizer to choose to spool and replay the source rows, and not replace the spool with a simple "table get" later on. For example, the initial transformation from full join looks like this:

[image: early plan]

Notice the extra spools introduced by the general transform. Spools above a simple table get are cleaned up later by the rule `SpoolGetToGet`.

If the optimizer had a corresponding `SpoolConstGetToConstGet` rule, it could work as you wish, in principle.

> How to get rid of it in this case, what are the possible ways?

Use a real table (temporary or variable), or write the transformation from full join manually, for example:

```
WITH 
    p([Id], [Code]) AS
    (
        SELECT @id1, 'A'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT @id2, 'B'
    ),
    FullJoin AS
    (
        SELECT
            p.Code,
            d.[Status]
        FROM p
        LEFT JOIN #data d 
            ON d.[Id] = p.[Id]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            NULL,
            D.[Status]
        FROM #data AS D
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM p
            WHERE p.Id = D.Id
        )
    )
SELECT
    COALESCE(FullJoin.Code, 'X') AS Code,
    COALESCE(FullJoin.Status, 0) AS [Status]
FROM FullJoin;
```

Plan for manual rewrite:

[image: Manual rewrite plan]

This has an estimated cost of 0.0067201 units, compared with 0.0203412 units for the original.

---

* It can be observed as a `LogOp_UnionAll` in the *Converted Tree* (TF 8605). In the *Input Tree* (TF 8606) it is a `LogOp_ConstTableGet`. The *Converted Tree* shows the tree of optimizer expression elements after parsing, normalization, algebrization, binding, and some other preparatory work. The *Input Tree* shows the elements after conversion to Negation Normal Form (NNF convert), runtime constant collapsing, and a few other bits and bobs. NNF convert includes logic to collapse logical unions and common table gets, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

The table spool is simply creating a table out of the two sets of tuples present in the `VALUES` clause.

You can eliminate the spool by inserting those values into a temp table first, like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #data;
CREATE TABLE #data ([Id] int, [Status] int);

INSERT INTO #data
VALUES (100, 1), (101, 2), (102, 3), (103, 2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #p;
CREATE TABLE #p
(
    Id int NOT NULL
    , Code char(1) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @id1 int = 101, @id2 int = 105;

INSERT INTO #p (Id, Code)
VALUES
        (@id1, 'A'),
        (@id2, 'B');


SELECT
    COALESCE(p.[Code], 'X') AS [Code],
    COALESCE(d.[Status], 0) AS [Status]
FROM #p p
    FULL JOIN #data d ON d.[Id] = p.[Id];
```

Looking at the execution plan for your query, we see the output list contains two columns that use the `Union` prefix; this is a hint that the spool is creating a table from a union'd source:

[image]

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` requires SQL Server to access the values in `p` twice, once for each "side" of the join.  Creating a spool allows the resulting inner loops join to access the spooled data.

Interestingly, if you replace the `FULL OUTER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`, and `UNION` the results together, SQL Server does not use a spool.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(p.[Code], 'X') AS [Code],
    COALESCE(d.[Status], 0) AS [Status]
FROM (VALUES
        (101, 'A'),
        (105, 'B')
    ) p([Id], [Code])
    LEFT JOIN #data d ON d.[Id] = p.[Id]
UNION
SELECT
    COALESCE(p.[Code], 'X') AS [Code],
    COALESCE(d.[Status], 0) AS [Status]
FROM (VALUES
        (101, 'A'),
        (105, 'B')
    ) p([Id], [Code])
    RIGHT JOIN #data d ON d.[Id] = p.[Id];
```

[image]

Note, I'm not suggesting using the `UNION` query above; for larger sets of input, it may not be more efficient than the simple `FULL OUTER JOIN` you already have.

Comment: In your real workload, is the spool really that costly?