# Constant Scan applying

Tags: sql-server, optimization, database-internals

This question is a continuation of optimizer behavior exploration in regards to `VALUES` construct started [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/244383/99746) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/245544/99746). I want to ask about `VALUES` and `APPLY` this time.

Using `CROSS APPLY` to alias an expression that needs to be referenced in various parts of a query is the common pattern. Such as, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #data (N int);
INSERT INTO #data VALUES (5), (4), (3), (2), (1);

SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (d.N * d.N)) c([Square])
WHERE c.[Square] BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY c.[Square];
```

I myself always use `CROSS APPLY` in such cases, but sometimes I encounter such expressions wrapped into inline-TVF and `OUTER APPLY`-ed. So, out of curiosity, I changed `CROSS` to `OUTER` in the exampling query

```sql
SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    OUTER APPLY (VALUES (d.N * d.N)) c([Square])
WHERE c.[Square] BETWEEN 1 AND 10
ORDER BY c.[Square];
```

to check if it matters.

To my understanding, semantics of `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` are equal in this case, since `VALUES (d.N * d.N)` always returns exactly one row for each row of `d`. My expectation was that the optimizer would produce identical execution plans for both (likewise it changes left join to inner sometimes). This is not the case however.

The `OUTER` modification has an execution plan resembling its written form. It has `APPLY` implemented as Nested Loops with expression computed in Constant Scan on the inner side. Then Filter is there to address `WHERE` predicate and Sort to address `ORDER BY` finally.

[image: OUTER APPLY plan]

Whereas the execution plan of the `CROSS` modification looks as if there were no `APPLY` at all and the expression has been substituted instead of its alias. It has `WHERE` predicate pushed to Table Scan. Then there is the Compute Scalar performing expression computation, and finally Sort as well.

[image: CROSS APPLY plan]

Why doesn't the optimizer want to get rid of `APPLY` in case of `OUTER`, like it did with `CROSS`? It has all the information in hands to conclude that `VALUES` produces exactly one row per each table row.

I understand that the answer can be short like *"It could in theory, but that's what current implementation is"*. So, to inspire on how to construct a more thorough answer, I have additional questions (going along the way) regarding optimization paths of these two queries.

In the remaining parts of the question, shortened queries are used:

```sql
SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (d.N * d.N)) c([Square]);

SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    OUTER APPLY (VALUES (d.N * d.N)) c([Square]);
```

They lack `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`. Despite that, they have all the necessary attributes, and have different execution plans as well.

**CROSS APPLY**

Let's start with the Input Tree (trace flag 8606). At this point, the logical tree corresponds well to the written form of the query.

```
*** Input Tree: ***
LogOp_Project QCOL: [d].N COL: Expr1002 
    LogOp_Apply (x_jtInner)
        LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
        LogOp_Project
            LogOp_ConstTableGet (1) [empty]
            AncOp_PrjList 
                AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1002 
                    ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult
                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
    AncOp_PrjList 
*******************
```

Then, before entering the simplification stage, an event named *projection pulling* happens. Optimizer pulls scalar expression computation above Apply

```
*** Before Simplification Tree (not visible with TF 8606) ***
LogOp_Project QCOL: [d].N COL: Expr1002 
    LogOp_Apply (x_jtInner)
        LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
        LogOp_ConstTableGet (1) [empty]
    AncOp_PrjList 
        AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1002 
            ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult
                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
*******************
```

What is the aim of pulling scalar expression above Apply? What are the things that inhibit pulling naturally, and is there a way to suppress it by force?

After that simplification stage begins and among the first rules being applied (trace flag 8621) `PrjApplyHandler` changes Apply to Join

```
***** Rule applied: Prj APPLY stack -> Prj Join stack
LogOp_Project
    LogOp_Join
        LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
        LogOp_ConstTableGet (1) [empty]
        ScaOp_Const TI(bit,ML=1) XVAR(bit,Not Owned,Value=1)
    AncOp_PrjList 
        ...
```

If being implemented at this stage, the execution plan of the query would look as follows:

[image: CROSS APPLY scalar pulled]

Then `SimplifyJoinWithCTG` rule gets into action. It removes cross join to empty single row `LogOp_ConstTableGet` leaving the `LogOp_Get` only

```
***** Rule applied: Join/LSJ(ConstTableGet(1),x0,True) --> x0
    LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
```

So, after all simplifications, the logical tree becomes

```
*** Simplified Tree: ***
LogOp_Project
    LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
    AncOp_PrjList 
        AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1002 
            ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult
                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
                ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
*******************
```

And then it flows, unchanged, up until being implemented trivially as

[image: CROSS APPLY final]

Disabling the `SimplifyJoinWithCTG` rule leads to the execution plan with scalar expression computation pushed below the join, but to its outer side

[image: CROSS APPLY scalar pushed]

(this plan has `JoinCommute` disabled also).

What is the aim of pushing the scalar expression below the join after it has been pulled above before?

**OUTER APPLY**

The Input Tree for `OUTER APPLY` modification is almost identical to that of the `CROSS APPLY`. The only difference is that `LogOp_Apply` has `x_jtLeftOuter` type

```
*** Input Tree: ***
LogOp_Project QCOL: [d].N COL: Expr1002 
    LogOp_Apply (x_jtLeftOuter)
        LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
        LogOp_Project
            LogOp_ConstTableGet (1) [empty]
            AncOp_PrjList 
                AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1002 
                    ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult
                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
                        ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
    AncOp_PrjList 
*******************
```

Starting from this point, things are very different for `OUTER APPLY`. The first difference is that projection pulling does not happen for scalar expression in this case. Why doesn't the optimizer pull the scalar expression for `OUTER APPLY`?

The second difference is that the optimizer does not change Apply to Join at simplification stage. Actually, even in the Output Tree (trace flag 8607), it is presented as `PhyOp_Apply`, and join appears as post-optimization only.

Despite that, `RedundantApplyOJ` and `ApplyHandler` simplification rules are applied

[image: RedundantApplyOJ applied]
[image: ApplyHandler applied]

there are no signs of it in the Simplified Tree

```
*** Simplified Tree: ***
LogOp_Apply (x_jtLeftOuter)
    LogOp_Get TBL: #data(alias TBL: d)
    LogOp_ConstTableGet (1) COL: Expr1002 
        ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopMult
            ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
            ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [d].N
*******************
```

Also, `SimplifyJoinWithCTG` rule is not even considered for `OUTER APPLY` (meaning that it has no chance to match or not match).

Then, after all simplifications are done, the logical tree flows, unchanged, up until being implemented at Quick Plan stage as

[image: OUTER APPLY final]

Why didn't the optimizer try to change Apply to Join at simplification stage for `OUTER APPLY` like it did it for `CROSS APPLY`? What `RedundantApplyOJ` and `ApplyHandler` rules do during simplification in this case? Are they something like *A*1=A* (meaning that nothing is changed effectively), or are they just change some properties of the logical tree nodes without affecting tree shape?

Comment: Ok, I was able to resolve most of the questions, will try to compile things into answer.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: @trusha, optimizer has all stuff to perform better optimization for `outer` (it can be optimized as good as `cross` in fact), but current implementation isn't flawless, projection pulling is the real blocker in the `outer` case (I mean the fact that it does not happen).

Comment: I actually use this "feature" sometimes as an optimization fence for complex expressions in the `APPLY`, to stop them being evaluated multiple times

Comment: @i-one This question has received a good number of upvotes, and is sounds like you were able to figure it out. Are you able to articulate it into an answer that might be useful to others?

Answer (score 1):

The Optimiser doesn’t know what the data is until the query is running. So it has to prepare for anything.

If you make the queries simpler and put 10 rows in the #data table, it becomes clearer that the FILTER guesstimates for the OUTER APPLY query are 50% of the #data table row-count.

The results of the OUTER APPLY c.[Square] result-set appears Non-deterministic.

APPLY will always use a Nested Loop unless it is safe to do something else. In this case it isn’t safe because the content is unknown and an OUTER APPLY can potentially produce NULL results for c.[Square].

Even if you set #data to (N int NOT NULL) the Nested Loop is still used and the Estimates are wrong because it’s the OUTER APPLY that is invisible to the Optimiser.

Note: Any filters on c.[Square] may not be NULL sensitive: “NULL <> 5” can produce unwanted results.

Here’s an example with #data containing 10 integers.

The Optimiser Estimates 5 rows will be returned from the OUTER APPLY

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #data
CREATE TABLE #data (N int);

INSERT INTO #data
SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY Object_id) FROM sys.columns

SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (d.N)) c([Square])
WHERE c.[Square] <> 5;

SELECT d.N, c.[Square]
FROM #data d
    OUTER APPLY (VALUES (d.N)) c([Square])
WHERE c.[Square] <> 5;
```

Hopefully there's someone who knows more about OUTER APPLY internals that can explain why the Optimiser is making blind guesses.....